# Unable to Install Tensorflow (MemoryError)

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to install Tensorflow on Linux Ubuntu 16.04 from source and using pip and I keep getting the following error **return base64.b64encode(b).decode("ascii")
MemoryError**. I tried to google this problem but only found a website written in Chinese (probably) http://juncollin.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/03/05/025318 that doesn't really help.

Comment: It's Japanese, that guy added a swap file to the system when he got that error because he thought there was not enough ram. Then he tried again but did not have enough disk space.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try installing without caching: `pip install --no-cache-dir tensorflow`.

Comment: if you don't use --no-cache-dir, pip stores the installation files for future use.

--no-cache-dir skips that step. (https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching)

Comment: I get this error: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.