# Tensorflow with raspberry pi 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I tried to install the tensorflow but I got an error message which is a memory error.

```
pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow
```

After I found a solution for that [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335087/unable-to-install-tensorflow-memoryerror). I use sudo command additionally.

```
sudo pip3 install --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```

Tensorflow was installed successfully for python 3.5.3 in raspberry pi 2.

When I tried following command which is recommended in google installation guide it is not working.

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.enable_eager_execution(); print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random_normal([1000, 1000])))"
```

Error massage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

After that, I tried to import tensorfolw library in Thonny `(import tensorflow as tf)` but I got following error message.

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.4 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.5
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 432, got 412
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

How to solve this error for raspberry pi?

**Updated.**

I tried to install again using `sudo pip3 install --no-cache-dir tensorflow` I got following error.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 937, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 799, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 583, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 190, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: I reomved pip becouse i got error when installing tensorflow. Only have pip3 but python 2 may be installed parallel python 3.5

Comment: @t.niese i edited code pip should be pip3. I used pip3 for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
`sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev 
pip3 install tensorflow`
```

Comment: Can you add a short description?

Comment: You can install tensorflow on raspberry pi by using the first command 'sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev' followed by 'pip3 install tensorflow' Use pip3 if you are using python 3 otherwise use pip. You can also follow this guide <https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi>